# Training a basic neural network that takes in a sequence of frame/number pairs and generates new numbers upon being given a new sequence of frames

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am very new to this topic so I am unsure about where to start with this task. I have a large amount of training data with is basically just a sequence of pictureframes with a number corresponding to each one. The sequence itself is kind of like a video that only changes bit by bit, which is also reflected in the corresponding numbers which never make any sort of "big jumps" and also only slowly change depending on various factors, such as speed at which the pixels change or at which pixels that once entered the screen exit again.

I have already tried looking up ways to set this up using keras, but a lot of the terminology and syntax is still foreign to me which is why i am unsure as to where to look for examples I could use for my particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using tensorflow instead:

```
#We start by importing everything that we will need

import tensorflow #This will train our model
import pandas    #Pandas is to read the data
import keras    
import numpy    #Numpy will build the matrices
import sklearn    #sklearn is to choose the model that we will be using
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import pickle    #pickle is used to save the model
from matplotlib import style


data = pandas.readcsv("path to the data", sep = ';') #You need to change the sep = ';'
#if your data is not separated with a ';'
data = data["Whatever","Label","you want","to include"]

predict = ["Label you want to predict"]

x = numpy.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = numpy.array(data[predict])
 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, 
test_size=0.3)

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
print(acc)

predictions = linear.predict[x_test]

for x in range(len(predictions)):
    print("Prediction:", predictions[x], "reality:", y_test[x]
```